# Can't create an opportune return for my function

Tags: javascript, function

I have to create a `function` that checks if a word is palindrome or not. My reasoning is to break down the word letter by letter, normal and reverse, and then compare the two results to determine if a word is a palindrome or not. With an `if - else` I give the user an alert that tells perfectly the result. Now, I've learned that most of the functions must have a `return` with a variable that contains that desired result.
In this case I really can't have this, I think it can work perfectly this way. I tried with

```
var palindromeResult = (leftToRightWord == rightToLeftWord) ? 'true':'false';
console.log(palindromeResult);    
return palindromeResult;
```

but it works only for the developer if he reads the console.log in the console, but it's a bad solution for me... Have you got any better idea than this? Below my full `function` code

```
function isPalindrome(wordToCheck) {
    for(var i = 0; i < wordToCheck.length; i++) {
        var leftToRightWord = wordToCheck[i];
        console.log('Left ' + leftToRightWord);
    }

    for(var j = wordToCheck.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        var rightToLeftWord = wordToCheck[j];
        console.log('Right ' + rightToLeftWord);
    }
    
    if ( leftToRightWord === rightToLeftWord) {
        alert('La parola è palindroma');
    } else {
        alert('La parola non è palindroma');
    }
```

Edit: At the end I changed a lot my code for a better legibility.

```
//Data
var userWord;

//I ask a word to the user
do {
    userWord = prompt("Dimmi una parola");
} while (userWord.length === 0)

//Here the result of the function is saved and it can be reused
var functionResult = isPalindrome(userWord);
console.log (functionResult);

//Function to know if the word inserted is a palindrome or not
//the cycle with rightToLeft reverse the word so it can be compared to the normal word
//A pop-up will give the solution so it can be seen clearly on your screen
//The function result will ben saved outside the function in var functionResult so it can be seen with a console.log or reused for whatever use
function isPalindrome(wordToCheck) {
    var rightToLeftWord = '';

    for(var j = wordToCheck.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    rightToLeftWord = rightToLeftWord + wordToCheck[j];
    }
    console.log(rightToLeftWord);

    var palindromeResult = wordToCheck == rightToLeftWord;
    alert(palindromeResult);
    return palindromeResult;
}
```

Now the cycle with for doesn't have problems anymore as you've pointed out to me and it correctly recognize if a word is a palindrome or not.

Comment: Tangential, but why so verbose? Why `var palindromeResult = (leftToRightWord == rightToLeftWord) ? 'true':'false';` instead of simply `var palindromeResult = leftToRightWord == rightToLeftWord`?

Comment: How are you calling the function and planning to use the `return` result?

Comment: "*it works only for the developer if he reads the console.log in the console, but it's a bad solution for me... Have you got any better idea than this?*" You haven't provided any semblance of what your target environment looks like (whether this is client-side with an HTML component, or server-side), but why not just write it to the DOM somewhere? (If anything in this comment is foreign to you, I would implore you to take a step back and brush up on your HTML and in-browser JavaScript fundamentals.)

Comment: You're right @esqew, but with that I tried to give a feedback in the console.log, with true and false

Comment: @Rojo with isPalindrome(word); in my mind a pop up, so an alert was the perfect way to give an instant feedback to someone who wanted to check if a word is a palindrome or not

Comment: @Alebacce I'm not sure how you arrived at the conclusion that the alternative I suggested above is incompatible with the rest of the snippet you provided. Did you try it?

Comment: @Alebacce Your current code appears to do just that (spawn an `alert()` with the result of the analysis) - what is your question, exactly?

Comment: Nothing so complicated, it was just an exercise I have to do for the school I'm attending. I'm not building anything, it was just to vìcreate a working function because it was the lesson of the day. I have good bases on HTML and frontend, but I'm new to Js and a foreigner to backend. For your other question yes I tried but no result was displayed

Comment: Probably it's my inexperience, maybe it's just alright this way. If it's the case I delete the post

Comment: _I've learned that most of the functions must have a return with a variable that contains that desired result._ it is not striclty true. If you return from your function then you alert. so in your case `alert(palindromeResult)` in your page (outside the function) as you do with console.log

Comment: If you just return _after_ the alert, you'll get both the alert and the result.

Comment: I solved and I posted everything in my question with an edit. Thanks everyone for the help, I've obtained exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

See the snippet. The function returns the answer and then you can alert it, assign it to a variable, echo it on the page and so on. I'm not pretty sure about your algorithm since it is telling me that 'abracadabra' is palindrome but it is not. RTL the sequence of the letters is wrong!

```js
function isPalindrome(wordToCheck) {
  for (var i = 0; i < wordToCheck.length; i++) {
    var leftToRightWord = wordToCheck[i];
    console.log('Left ' + leftToRightWord);
  }

  for (var j = wordToCheck.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    var rightToLeftWord = wordToCheck[j];
    console.log('Right ' + rightToLeftWord);
  }

  if (leftToRightWord === rightToLeftWord) {
    return 'La parola è palindroma';
  } else {
    return 'La parola non è palindroma';
  }
}

alert(isPalindrome('abracadabra'));
```

Comment: Thank you, thank to your suggestion I noticed an error that I was unable to see!